# php database error in codenighter frame work

Tags: php, database

I am using codenighter framework and i have a problem with database like when I add teacher to my database it gives me error of default value cannot be null as shown in the picture but the data entered in the database...
error picture is this: [image]

and the fields in the teacher table are:

```
teacher_id
name,
birthday,
sex,
religion,
blood_group,
address,
phone,
email,
password,
authentication_key
```

and the filed in the view are:

```
teacher_id  
name,  
birthday,  
sex,  
religion,  
blood_group,  
address,  
phone,  
email,  
password,  
image
```

Comment: Can you please show your html markup? i'm guessing that controllers/admin.php is not getting any information from POST request

Answer (score 1):

Did you fill up all the forms? Can you do a var_dump of the post data?

Name field seems to be "not null" in database. So you are required to pass in name value as well.